# Entropy solution - Burgers' equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, characteristics, hyperbolic-equations

Why doesn't the following problem have a solution for $t\ge1$?

$u_{t}+uu_{x}=0\\
u(0,x)=-x$.

The characteristics don't intersect and they cover the whole space above t=1.

Answer (score 1):

All characteristics intersect at $(t,x) = (1, 0)$.

Indeed, the characteristic starting from $(0, x_0)$ is $x(t) = x_0 - x_0 \, t = (1-t) x_0$.

Comment: I wrongly thought that in one point it doesn't matter, since the rest doesn't overlap. So if I follow a characteristic from a point above t=1, when I get to (1,0)," I don't know where to go from there". 
If I would want to give a precise argument, is it okay saying that R-H condition isn't satisfied for any shock curve?

Comment: There is no characterist going beyond the time $t=1$ (after intersecting $x=0$); here the problem is that the speed is not bounded.