# Burgers' equation (method of characteristics)

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Find the solution to given equation on $[0, 1) \times \mathbb{R}$ and prove there is no solution for $ t \ge 1$
\begin{cases}
u_t+\left(\frac{u^2}{2} \right)_x =0 & \text{in }\mathbb{R}\times(0,\infty) \\
\qquad \qquad \, \, u=g & \text{on } \mathbb{R} \times\{t=0\}
\end{cases}
Let $g(x) = -x.$

By the method of characteristics I got  \begin{cases}
x(t) = -x_0t + x_0 \\
u(x,t) = g(x_0) = \dfrac{x}{1-t}
\end{cases}

For $t = 1$ solution does not exist, how would I prove for $t >1$?

If we introduce characteristic function $g(x) = -\chi_{[a,b]}x$  would we then be able to define solution for $t \ge 1 ?$ (Region where $g(x) = 0$ and characteristics do not cross we can put $u(x,t)=x_0$ for all $t\ge 0$)

Any hints or help is welcome. Thanks

Comment: What brand of solution are we talking about? classical solution? weak solution? entropy solution?

Comment: For the first part of the problem it is not explicitly said what kind of solution we are looking for (my guess would be classical ?).
For characteristic function problem we are looking for entropy solution.

Comment: yeah I was only asking about second

Comment: Here is [the reason why](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2589157/418542) $t<1$. Other related posts: [(1)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2595293/418542)  [(2)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2588945/418542)

Comment: See for the second question with $g(x) = - \chi_{[a, b]} x $ [my shameless self-cited proposal](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4397555/805029).